# php code to select max value and display count of max value in table

Tags: php, mysql

table name voter
fields name - partyname,state,direction,candidatename,district,votes
date in table is like wise

```
BJP Maharashtra Nagpur-East Nitin Gadkari   Nagpur  3000    
Congress    Maharashtra Nagpur-East Lucky   Nagpur  2500    
BJP Maharashtra Nagpur-South    Rakesh  Nagpur  12000   
Congress    Maharashtra Nagpur-South    Shyam   Nagpur  15000
```

i am selecting max votes from table on where condition of state,direction and district wise.
and display vote below.

now i want to ask you how to get above  query result and display count of how much max value in my table on each direction.
plz suggest me......
i only need to display count of max value direcion wise.

for ex---
direction     votes     party 
east           5000      bjp
east           8000      aap
then there is only 1 max value in east direction then it display count 1..
plz tell me....

```
<table class="bordered">
    <tr> 
    <?php           
        $sqlst = "SELECT DISTINCT state FROM voter_count";
        $resultst = mysql_query($sqlst);
        while($rowst = mysql_fetch_array($resultst,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
        ?>  
    <td> 
<table class="bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>             
        <th colspan="3"><?php echo $rowst['state']; ?></th>
    </tr>

     <?php  
        $state = $rowst["state"];           
        $sqlco = "SELECT DISTINCT district,direction FROM voter_count where state = '$state'";          
        $resultco = mysql_query($sqlco);
        while($rowco = mysql_fetch_array($resultco,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
        ?>    
     <tr>   
         <?php      
        $district = $rowco['district'];         
        $direction = $rowco['direction'];       
        $sqlvotes = "SELECT  MAX(votes) AS Vote,direction FROM voter_count where state = '$state' AND district = '$district' AND direction = '$constituency'";              
        $resultvotes = mysql_query($sqlvotes);                      
        while($rowvotes = mysql_fetch_array($resultvotes,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {               

        ?>   
         <th><?php echo $rowvotes['Vote']; ?></th>      
          <th><?php echo $rowvotes['direction']; ?></th>         
    </tr>
    <?php }  } ?>
    </thead>
    </table>
</td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: try GROUP BY

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what your final table needs to look like, but this is a start (you don't need your first query, you can do what you want with one query):

```
  SELECT  MAX(votes) AS Vote,direction, state, district FROM voter_count
  group by direction, state, district
```

As one of the comments mentioned refer to this link about how to use group by:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

i am not so clear with what you are upto if you are using a single table for storage.

i would suggest you to

**make two tables** one for id,state,direction,district

and another for id,fkid(district's id),partyname,candidatename,votes

**this makes your task easier**.

then

```
 $con  =    db_connect();
 $str   =   "select a.state,a.direction,a.district
             from tabel1 as a 
             inner join tabel2 as b
             on b.fkid=a.id ";

    $result =   mysql_query($str,$con);

    while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<pre>";print_r($arr); //prints all values as a  formatted array Use these values in your tabel.
    }
```